# How to call cuSparse when ALL arguments are in device memory?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I have a code which uses cusparseDgemmi to multiply a sparse vector with a dense vector:

```
cusparseDgemmi(cusparsehandle,cols,cols,cols,nnz,&al,G,
        cols,cscVal,cscColPtr,cscRowInd,
        &bet,SE,cols);
```

where `cusparsehandle`, `cols`, `nnz`, `al`, and `bet` are in host memory and the rest are in device memory. The above works fine.

Now suppose I first move `cols` to device memory and then call cusparse:

```
//d_cols->cols
int *d_cols,*p_cols;
p_cols=&cols;
printf("%d\n",*p_cols);
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_cols,sizeof(int));
cudaMemcpy(d_cols,p_cols, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

//...

//call cusparse with *d_cols instead of cols
cusparseDgemmi(cusparsehandle,*d_cols,*d_cols,*d_cols,nnz,&al,G,
        *d_cols,cscVal,cscColPtr,cscRowInd,
        &bet,SE,*d_cols);
```

The code will compile but crash at run time. The cusparse reference manual says that the ["cuSPARSE API assumes that input and output data reside in GPU (device) memory, unless it is explicitly indicated otherwise by the string DevHostPtr"](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html)

If this is the case, then why does my code run fine when `cols` is in host memory but not when it is in device memory? How do I call cusparse when all the arguments arguments of the cusparse function be in device memory. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The cusparse reference manual says that the "cuSPARSE API assumes that
>   input and output data reside in GPU (device) memory, unless it is
>   explicitly indicated otherwise by the string DevHostPtr"

The [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#scalar-parameters2) actually says that alpha and beta can be passed as pointers in device or host memory, depending on the pointer mode settings you use. And that is all it says. And what you are trying to do has nothing to do with that.

What you are really asking is "Can I dereference a device pointer in host code?", and the answer is obviously no, and is the source of the segfault you see.

The only way you can make this work would be to (on platforms which support it) allocate those other parameters using managed memory, so that they are valid pointers on both host and device, and dereference them as part of the cuSparse calls. Note that there will be a performance penalty in doing so.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This makes sense.